# How to add a JVM option to glassfish 4.0?

Tags: glassfish-4, asadmin

The glassfish administation guide states that JVM options ought to be added with `asadmin create-jvm-options -Dkey=value:-Dkey=value` (https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf, S. 120). Of course the examples don't include the interesting and pedagogical important case of adding options containing `:` and options starting with `-XX` instead of `-D`. It is explained to escape `:` with `\`, though. Invoking `asadmin create-jvm-options -XX\:MaxPermSize=1024m:-Xmx4096` adds the two options without removing `\` which (correctly) prevents the (wrong) option to be recognized. What is the correct way to proceed here?

How to overwrite existing options? If the option name is specified with the same value, `asadmin create-jvm-options` complains that the option is already present, the another value is specified, the values are both present (-> which one is used?). I don't really have to parse and evaluate the output of `asadmin list-jvm-options`, do I?

How do I find out whether the options have been added or not, i.e. whether I have to restart the domain? Same question here: I don't really have to parse and evaluate the output of `asadmin list-jvm-options` before and after adding options, do I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the correct way to proceed here?

You have to delete the JVM option with `asadmin delete-jvm-options`:

```
asadmin delete-jvm-options '-XX\:MaxPermSize=192m'
```

Then add the option again with the new value:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options '-XX\:MaxPermSize=1024m'
```

**A restart of the server is always required after changing JVM options.**

> How to overwrite existing options? If the option name is specified
>   with the same value, `asadmin create-jvm-options` complains that the
>   option is already present, the another value is specified, the values
>   are both present (-> which one is used?). I don't really have to parse
>   and evaluate the output of `asadmin list-jvm-options`, do I?

I guess this problem is obsolete if you follow the above instructions.

> How do I find out whether the options have been added or not, i.e.
>   whether I have to restart the domain? Same question here: I don't
>   really have to parse and evaluate the output of `asadmin
>   list-jvm-options` before and after adding options, do I?

The `asadmin` command tells you if it has successfully added or deleted an option. If you try to delete an option which doesn't exist, `asadmin` will tell you that no option was deleted because it didn't exist.

**Update:**

> In order to delete option I have to know both key and value (what do I
>   do if the option set is -XX:MaxPermSize=193m -> it won't be deleted,
>   but asadmin will produce a second option (the order is unclear),
>   therefore I would have to parse the output of asadmin
>   list-jvm-options).

Why should it have the value `193m` if you didn't set that before (and then you probably know it)? And if it has this value, yes you are right, you would have to parse the output of `list-jvm-options` to find it out. You could also write a script which tries to delete the value by increasing the parameter (`192m`, `193m`, `194m` and so on), but that would take a long time to complete.

> How does asadmin tell me this (return code, output, ...)?

It outputs human-readable messages like this:

```
deleted 1 option(s)
Command delete-jvm-options executed successfully.
```

or

```
created 1 option(s)
Command create-jvm-options executed successfully.
```

Try for yourself to see the different messages.

> I'm referring to GF 4.0, so links to the 3.0.1 admin guide are
>   obsolete.

They aren't, the GlassFish administration and `asadmin` are 99,9% equal in GlassFish 3 and 4.

> What about the escaping issue?

I can't reproduce that, maybe it helps to set only one value at a time or to wrap param and value in quotation marks.

**See also:**

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Administration Guide - To Delete JVM Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggnfi/index.html)
- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Administration Guide - Administering JVM Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gepzd/index.html)

Comment: In order to delete option I have to know both key and value (what do I do if the option set is `-XX\:MaxPermSize=193m` -> it won't be deleted, but `asadmin` will produce a second option (the order is unclear), therefore I would have to parse the output of `asadmin list-jvm-options`). To your second point: **How** does `asadmin` tell me this (return code, output, ...)? I'm referring to GF 4.0, so links to the 3.0.1 admin guide are obsolete (I'm even referencing the right version in my question...). What about the escaping issue?

Comment: Thank you :)! The result is the worst I expected. (1) What's the sense in specifying different `-Xmx` options; overwriting should occur based on keys and evict all values! (2) Unspecified return codes almost are a kind of sadism by the developer(s) (I was hoping for input beyong the admin guide towards a sophisticated technical specification). I think my question and you answer show that this admin guide is quite unusable/useless.

Comment: If you use single quotes don't escape inline colons, otherwise the create will fail.  So for multiple options you could do this:
 
    `asadmin create-jvm-options '-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures':'-XX:+FlightRecorder'`

Answer (score 1):

[glassfish@6b99de007186 /]$ asadmin delete-jvm-options -client:'-XX:MaxPermSize=192m':-Xmx512m
Deleted 3 option(s)
Command delete-jvm-options executed successfully.

[glassfish@6b99de007186 /]$ asadmin create-jvm-options -server:'-XX:MaxPermSize=256m':-Xmx1024m
Created 3 option(s)
Command create-jvm-options executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative to command line is add the JVM properties manually to the Glassfish domain.xml file.

You can find that file in:
pat-to-glassgish\Glassfish\glassfish\domains\yourdomain\config

There you will see a secion for jvm-options, like this:

```
<jvm-options>-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2</jvm-options>
```

You can add yours in there.

I hope it helps :-)